# Removing duplicates every X number of lines

Tags: text-processing, awk

Is it possible to remove only the `AWD015F11` duplicate using Awk? I have a large file with one column. This happens every 24 rows.

I have tried counting the rows in search for a pattern that I could use. As you can see there are other duplicate rows but the problem is only with `AWD015F11`.

```
5000
5000
false
false
AWD015F11
425
25
34
1
5000
5000
320
320
OH,AWD015F
false
true
8
50
32
0
5
9
9
true
-34
0
false
false
AWD015F11
AWD015G21
```

Comment: a) Is every 24th row (after row 5) always going to contains this string, and hence will always be removed? (b) Do you have to use awk?

Comment: r.a) It is every 24 rows once AWD####### shows up. The output would be the basically showing only the first AWD015F11. r.b) It can also be sed or unix shell.

Comment: I don't understand. Is the string to remove always going to be `AWD015F11`? Is it whatever is on the 24th column? How can the script know not to remove the duplicates you actually want? What is `AWD#######`? Is that supposed to represent `AWD` followed by any 7 characters? Does `OH,AWD015F` count? I don't see any cases of `AWD` and 7 characters. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. Show us a sample that reproduces the issue and show us the output you would like to see.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `PERL`, use the code below to remove all duplicate from the file. It will print first unique AWD###### line, and the remaining following this anywhere in the file will not be printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
%data=();
foreach $r ( <STDIN> ) {
    chomp($r);
    if($r =~ /^AWD[A-Za-z0-9]{6}$/){
        if(!exists($data{$r})){
            $data{$r} = 1;
            print "$r\n";
        }
    } else {
        print "$r\n";
    }
}
```

Link to ideone: http://ideone.com/0SFQQ4

I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this attempt to answer. I apologize for not explaining the part where 015F11 varies. Therefore, the only fix pattern is that every 24 rows, I need to remove a duplicate that starts with AWD######.

Comment: @CurryMurtag is AWD###### of constant lenght. And I don't see how `AWD015F11
AWD015G21` comes every 24 rows,

Comment: Yes, the length is a constant. This is just a fraction of the file to illustrate the issue. Just imagine, once AWD015G21 shows up, 24 rows later, it shows up once again.

Comment: @CurryMurtag I have changed my answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get the script to run.

Comment: @CurryMurtag What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
awk '!/^AWD015F11$/ {print $0}; /^AWD015F11$/ && found<1 {found++; print $0}' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo | wc -l
30

$ awk '!/^AWD015F11$/ {print $0}; /^AWD015F11$/ && found<1 {found++; print $0}' foo | wc -l
29

$ cat foo
5000
5000
false
false
AWD015F11
425
25
34
1
5000
5000
320
320
OH,AWD015F
false
true
8
50
32
0
5
9
9
true
-34
0
false
false
AWD015F11
AWD015G21

$ awk '!/^AWD015F11$/ {print $0}; /^AWD015F11$/ && found<1 {found++; print $0}' foo
5000
5000
false
false
AWD015F11
425
25
34
1
5000
5000
320
320
OH,AWD015F
false
true
8
50
32
0
5
9
9
true
-34
0
false
false
AWD015G21
```

Comment: I like this approach. It does the job, but partially. Is it possible to get what awk is suppose to search, from another file? I mean, what's between /^#########$/

Answer (score -1):

```
n=$(set '' p n p n;printf "\n%b$@$@$@$@$@$@\n \c")
sed -ne"/^AWD015F11/{:n$n$n};s///;t" -ep <in
```

works with `sed`. It just does `n;p` 23 times after seeing `^AWD` and then refuses to print same.

Comment: When trying this solution, I get: sed: -e expression #2, char 116: extra characters after command

Comment: @Curry_Montag - i changed it to make it easier to enter on the command line. I suspect the issue either had to do with either the trailing newline that needed appending to `$n`'s definition, or the shell doing psycho history expansion on a quoted `!` - i really hate it when they do that. So i altered the quoting a little and expand `$n`'s definition w/ a little `set/printf` macro in a subshell.

Comment: This is a good option but I am afraid it needs some adjustments since it is removing all instances of whatever is between /^#########/ and it is only suppose to remove the second one

Comment: @CurryMurtag - i didn't get the message you left the other day for whatever reason. I think i;ve got it to print only the first of any two paired occurrences. What is `/^###.../`?

Comment: @CurryMurtag - just checked it out - it works just fine.

Comment: @CurryMurtag+ yo... this have anything to do with `gitsed`?